# Example of OpenGL game coordinates system - done right?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Well it is not surprise what default OpenGL screen coords system quite hard to operate with x-axis: from -1.0 to 1.0, y-axis: from -1.0 to 1.0, and (0.0,0.0) in center of screen.

So i decided to write some wrapper to local game coords with next main ideas:

1. Screen coords will be 0..100.0 (x-axis), 0..100.0 (y-axis) with (0.0,0.0) in bottom left corner of screen.
2. There are different screens, with different aspects.
3. If we draw quad, it must stay quad, not squashed rectangle.

By the **quad** i mean

```
quad_vert[0].x = -0.5f;
quad_vert[0].y = -0.5f;
quad_vert[0].z =  0.0f;

quad_vert[1].x =  0.5f;
quad_vert[1].y = -0.5f;
quad_vert[1].z =  0.0f;

quad_vert[2].x = -0.5f;
quad_vert[2].y =  0.5f;
quad_vert[2].z =  0.0f;

quad_vert[3].x =  0.5f;
quad_vert[3].y =  0.5f;
quad_vert[3].z =  0.0f;
```

I will use glm::ortho  and glm::mat4 to achieve this:

```
#define LOC_SCR_SIZE 100.0f

typedef struct coords_manager
{
 float SCREEN_ASPECT;
 mat4 ORTHO_MATRIX;//glm 4*4 matrix
}coords_manager;

glViewport(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);

coords_manager CM;

CM.SCREEN_ASPECT = (float) screen_width / screen_height;
```

For example our aspect will be 1.7

```
CM.ORTHO_MATRIX = ortho(0.0f, LOC_SCR_SIZE, 0.0f, LOC_SCR_SIZE);
```

Now bottom left is (0,0) and top right is (100.0, 100.0)

And it works, well mostly, now we can translate our quad to (25.0, 25.0), scale it to (50.0, 50.0) and it will sit at bottom-left corner with size of 50% percent of screen.
But problem is what it not quad anymore it looks like rectangle, because our screen width not equal with height.

So we use our screen aspect:

```
CM.ORTHO_MATRIX = ortho(0.0f, LOC_SCR_SIZE * CM.SCREEN_ASPECT, 0.0f, LOC_SCR_SIZE);
```

Yeah we get right form but another problem - if we position it at (50,25) we get it kinda left then center of screen, because our local system is not 0..100 x-axis anymore, it's now 0..170 (because we multiply by our aspect of 1.7), so we use next function before setting our quad translation

```
void loc_pos_to_gl_pos(vec2* pos)
{
 pos->x = pos->x * CM.SCREEN_ASPECT;
}
```

And viola, we get right form squad at right place.

But question is - am i doing this right?

Comment: IIRC the texture co-ords etc all work like this too. So might be alot of work to implement across the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenGL screen coords system quite hard to operate with x-axis: from -1.0 to 1.0, y-axis: from -1.0 to 1.0, and (0.0,0.0) in center of screen.

Yes, but you will never use them directly. There's usually always a projection matrix, that transforms your coordinates into the right space.

> we get it kinda left then center of screen, because our local system is not 0..100 x-axis anymore,

That's why OpenGL maps NDC space (0,0,0) to the screen center. If you draw a quad with coordinates symmetrically around the origin it will stay in the center.

> But question is - am i doing this right?

Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: So it better make my system symmetrical with 0.0 in center?
Projection ortho matrix will be CM.ORTHO_MATRIX = ortho(-LOC_SCR_SIZE * CM.SCREEN_ASPECT, LOC_SCR_SIZE * CM.SCREEN_ASPECT, -LOC_SCR_SIZE, LOC_SCR_SIZE);

Comment: @Aristarhys: There's no "one-size-fits-all" solution. You choose the projection and modelview transforms according to the task at hand. Also you're not limited to only one projection throughout rendering a frame. You can, and actually should adjust it for whatever you're drawing. You're drawing some 3D world: Use a projection. Then you draw some HUD on top of it, so you switch to a ortho projection.